# How Do I Open Paint Maximized with a File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to open MSPAINT maximized and open a file at the same time. I know how to open a file with paint and view an image, but I can't manage to open paint with an image and having paint maximized.

Here is my code:

```
static void Butten1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo() {
        FileName = "mspaint.exe",
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
        };
        Process.Start(Info);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass in the file name as parameter.

```
var filePath = @"C:\icon.png";
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "mspaint.exe",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized,
    Arguments = filePath
};
Process.Start(Info);
```

*Note that it works only because Paint interprets the first parameter as a file to open. It means that this solution will work only for Paint and other apps that try to open what's passed in as a first parameter.*